# why safari cut half page?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, safari

When I check my site in the Safari browser, if the first page I go to with the browser, if the total size of the content of that page is less than 100vh, Safari cuts the page and shows half of the page.
When in body I set min-height to 110vh in CSS, my problem is solved.
Does anyone have a better solution or know why this happens or have you ever used this method in your project?

Answer (score 1):

safari has a strange behavior when it comes to calculating the amount in vh. Safari calculates among other things the URL tab and any toolbars to the size.

The only approach so far is to calculate the height dynamically.

```css
.my-element {
    height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
}
```

or in javascript on the resize event

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
    var vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
});
```